# using lzo1c_1_compress method in lzo dll

Tags: c#, c++, lzo

Hi I want to compress a file using lzo in C#
I want to compress it with `lzo1c_1_compress` but I don't know why its not working at all and make the program crash, here is my code

```cs
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace Lzo64
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Wrapper class for the highly performant LZO compression library
    /// </summary>
    public class LZOCompressor
    {
        private static TraceSwitch _traceSwitch = new TraceSwitch("Simplicit.Net.Lzo", "Switch for tracing of the LZOCompressor-Class");
        private const string LzoDll32Bit = @"lib32\lzo2.dll";
        private const string LzoDll64Bit = @"lib64\lzo2_64.dll";

        #region Dll-Imports


        [DllImport(LzoDll64Bit)]
        private static extern int __lzo_init_v2(uint v, int s1, int s2, int s3, int s4, int s5, int s6, int s7, int s8, int s9);

        //[DllImport(LzoDll32Bit)]
        //private static extern int __lzo_init3();
        [DllImport(LzoDll64Bit)]
        private static extern IntPtr lzo_version_string();
        [DllImport(LzoDll32Bit, EntryPoint = "lzo_version_string")]
        private static extern IntPtr lzo_version_string32();
        [DllImport(LzoDll64Bit)]
        private static extern string lzo_version_date();
        [DllImport(LzoDll64Bit)]
        private static extern int lzo1c_1_compress(byte[] src, int src_len, byte[] dst, ref int dst_len, byte[] wrkmem);
        [DllImport(LzoDll64Bit)]
        private static extern int lzo1c_decompress(byte[] src, int src_len, byte[] dst, ref int dst_len, byte[] wrkmem);

        [DllImport(LzoDll32Bit, EntryPoint = "lzo1c_1_compress", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        private static extern int lzo1c_1_compress32(byte[] src, int src_len, byte[] dst, ref int dst_len, byte[] wrkmem);
        [DllImport(LzoDll32Bit, EntryPoint = "lzo1c_decompress", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        private static extern int lzo1c_decompress32(byte[] src, int src_len, byte[] dst, ref int dst_len, byte[] wrkmem);
        [DllImport(LzoDll32Bit, EntryPoint = "__lzo_init_v2", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        private static extern int __lzo_init_v2_32(uint v, int s1, int s2, int s3, int s4, int s5, int s6, int s7, int s8, int s9);

        #endregion

        private byte[] _workMemory = new byte[16384L * 4];

        public LZOCompressor()
        {
            int init = 0;
            if (Is64Bit())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Im 64Bit");
                init = __lzo_init_v2(1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Im 32Bit");
                init = __lzo_init_v2_32(1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1);
            }
            if (init != 0)
            {
                throw new Exception("Initialization of LZO-Compressor failed !");
            }
        }



        /// <summary>
        /// Version string of the compression library.
        /// </summary>
        public string Version
        {
            get
            {
                IntPtr strPtr;
                if (Is64Bit())
                    strPtr = lzo_version_string();
                else
                    strPtr = lzo_version_string32();

                string version = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(strPtr);
                return version;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Version date of the compression library
        /// </summary>
        public string VersionDate
        {
            get
            {
                return lzo_version_date();
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Compresses a byte array and returns the compressed data in a new
        /// array. You need the original length of the array to decompress it.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="src">Source array for compression</param>
        /// <returns>Byte array containing the compressed data</returns>
        public byte[] Compress(byte[] src)
        {
            if (_traceSwitch.TraceVerbose)
            {
                Trace.WriteLine(String.Format("LZOCompressor: trying to compress {0}", src.Length));
            }
            byte[] dst = new byte[src.Length + src.Length / 64 + 16 + 3 + 4];
            int outlen = 0;
            if (Is64Bit())
                lzo1c_1_compress(src, src.Length, dst, ref outlen, _workMemory);
            else
                lzo1c_1_compress32(src, src.Length, dst, ref outlen, _workMemory);

            if (_traceSwitch.TraceVerbose)
            {
                Trace.WriteLine(String.Format("LZOCompressor: compressed {0} to {1} bytes", src.Length, outlen));
            }
            byte[] ret = new byte[outlen + 4];
            Array.Copy(dst, 0, ret, 0, outlen);
            byte[] outlenarr = BitConverter.GetBytes(src.Length);
            Array.Copy(outlenarr, 0, ret, outlen, 4);
            return ret;
        }

        private bool _calculated;
        private bool _is64bit;
        private bool Is64Bit()
        {
            if (!_calculated)
            {
                _is64bit = IntPtr.Size == 8;
                _calculated = true;
            }
            return _is64bit;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Decompresses compressed data to its original state.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="src">Source array to be decompressed</param>
        /// <returns>Decompressed data</returns>
        public byte[] Decompress(byte[] src)
        {
            if (_traceSwitch.TraceVerbose)
            {
                Trace.WriteLine(String.Format("LZOCompressor: trying to decompress {0}", src.Length));
            }
            int origlen = BitConverter.ToInt32(src, src.Length - 4);
            byte[] dst = new byte[origlen];
            int outlen = origlen;
            if (Is64Bit())
                lzo1c_decompress(src, src.Length - 4, dst, ref outlen, _workMemory);
            else
                lzo1c_decompress32(src, src.Length - 4, dst, ref outlen, _workMemory);

            if (_traceSwitch.TraceVerbose)
            {
                Trace.WriteLine(String.Format("LZOCompressor: decompressed {0} to {1} bytes", src.Length, origlen));
            }
            return dst;
        }


    }

}
```

anyone know what im doing wrong?
if I use any other method like `lzo1x_1_compress` its working without problem
thanks

Comment: `lzo_uint` is [documented](https://github.com/nemequ/lzo/blob/master/doc/LZOAPI.TXT#L84) to match `size_t`. `size_t` is `IntPtr`. So all `src_len` and `dst_len` must match the size of `IntPtr` of the respective architecture. I would also set up `[In]` and `[Out]` attributes on the array arguments, and explicitly specify `MarshalAs(LPArray)`.

Comment: @GSerg thank you for help, im new in c# so im not sure about what you saying, can you please add a example?

Comment: Here is a version that seem to work: https://pastebin.com/raw/pF5r9W0w

Answer (score 1):

I see one issue:

1. VersionDate does not have a 64/32 bit check so you are always calling the 64 bit version assuming it is called by your main program for both 64/32 cases which I can not tell because you did not post your usage of your code example.  (You don't say in your question if you are crashing on 64/32 or both).

Comment: VersionData is not an important function, its used to just check the version of dll and that all, and about my usage, I wanted to compress a file using lz1c compression, in the end I come up with an Idea that worked, first I build a static version of lzo, then I created a new c++ dll project and include static lzo inside of it, and exported just those function that I needed, suddenly its worked, im still not sure what was the problem with c# code (maybe its something about dll itself..!)